# SDL2 and CMake on OS X 10.11

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

I know there are some answers (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136857/libsdl-cmake-and-mac-os-x-lion), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163670/libsdl-cmake-and-mac-os-x-lion-2) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395833/using-sdl2-with-cmake)), but I can't get it to work:

Consider a MWE *main.cpp*

```
// depending on the source of the example,
// one of the two includes is used
//#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "SDL.h"

int main() {
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I [downloaded](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) SDL2 v2.0.4 on OS X 10.11 and copied the *SDL2.framework* file into the */Library/Frameworks* folder.

Now I am trying to find a working CMake script to compile *main.cpp*.

First i tried

```
find_package(SDL)
add_executable(example main.cpp)
target_include_directories(example ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(example ${SDL_LIBRARY})
```

But I get the error message

```
Could NOT find SDL (missing:  SDL_LIBRARY) (found version "2.0.4")
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (target_include_directories):
  target_include_directories called with invalid arguments
```

If I included [FindSDL2.cmake](https://github.com/brendan-w/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake#L50) in a *cmake* subdirectory and use the script

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(example main.cpp)
```

CMake works, but I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do you have any idea what my problems are and how I can use SDL2 properly this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET ${SDL2_LIBRARY})` for your target - it's not linking against sdl.

If you run `make VERBOSE=1` you can see the actual link.

Comment: fixed.  commas, quotes, semicolons... my cmake is awful